An optimized approach for incrementally updating small updates for Mapbox Tileset source?
During my experiment, my case is that the initial GeoJSON data is rather large. I use Mapbox's Tilesets CLI The GeoJSON is export to GeoJSON file and upload to Tileset source and publish for Tileset. Each day, new Geometries or changes in existing geometries must be reflected to the Tileset. So I export an entire whole GeoJSON data and upload the new GeoJSON file to the tileset.
Is there any way for Tilesets CLI to make a small changes update to Mapbox Tileset source and publish to Tileset without having to re-tile the entire Mapbox Tileset source?
Mainly because I am concerned about the processing quota the Mapbox has for processing 30cm resolution.
Mapbox official suggest 3 methods

Create a new tileset source with --replace in the command upload-source to which delete the previous tileset source and create a new one.
Append to an existing tileset source to use Mapbox API Endpoint for adding source data to existing tileset-source.

The method 2) seems fit my needs but does Tileset CLI has such function? I couldn't find the function for update source.
